# Could I use memcached as a channel layer in Django?

Tags: python, django, memcached, django-channels, channel

I would like to use Django Channels in my application and I need a channel layer but I don't want to use Redis because, it is not available in my hosting plan. I have to get a dedicated or VPS server and I'm not ready for this yet.

Instead, Memcached is available. I have searched the documentation of channels and Django and the internet I found nothing about it. But I know that before Redis, Memcached was used to implement the same.

Basically I would like to configure my settings.py like that

```
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_mencached.core.MemcachedChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "host": "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672/",
        },
    },
}
```

This is really a pseudocode, in reality I have no idea about how to configure Django for Memcached. I know Memcached is not officially supported but, is there a way to hack it and make it work on Django? If not, is there any alternative to be used in production, aside from Redis and RabbigMQ?

Comment: It´s a shame that nobody answered this question. Normal people, especially developers working on new projects can´t afford a dedicated or VPS server, but still need to use more realistic alternatives to redis. A good answer to questions like that would add a huge help for the topic.